# Laravel Sanctum testing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-testing, laravel-sanctum

I'm trying to test my API auth methods, so I created ConfirmPasswordControllerTest with:

```
/** @test */
public function confirm_password_confirms()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();
    $data = ['password' => 'password'];

    $response = $this->actingAs($user)
                ->post('api/password-confirmation', $data);

    dd($response);
    $response->assertStatus(200);
}
```

I use dd() to check error messages in the response and I see all time:

```
RuntimeException: Session store not set on request.
```

I can't understand what happens here, I'm using Laravel Sanctum so my api routes have the auth:sanctum middleware.

EDIT:
If I don't include any data in the post like:

```
$response = $this->postJson('api/password-confirmation');
```

The test runs as expected:

```
{"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"password":["The password field is required."]}}
```

EDIT 2:
I debug the app and I see the problem is with the PasswordConfirmController:

```
public function confirm(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate($this->rules(), $this->validationErrorMessages());

    $this->resetPasswordConfirmationTimeout($request); //HERE

    return $request->wantsJson()
                ? new Response('', 204)
                : redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

It calls resetPasswordConfirmationTimeout() and this method need to use a session:

```
protected function resetPasswordConfirmationTimeout(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->put('auth.password_confirmed_at', time());
}
```